# How do I state that an actor featured in a movie? (e.g. "Michael Fassbender is in it.")

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

If the context were the following:

> I really like that movie. Michael Fassbender is in it.

How would I go about saying this? I tried searching but couldn't think of any decent keywords to find a similar thread.

> Michael Fassbender aparece [en esta película].

Would that be appropriate to say without the section in brackets or would it sound a bit broken?

If it varies depending on the country then European Spanish is the variant I'd prefer.

Comment: It depends on the context. The answer of @fedorqui shows you many examples. But I wanna add if the actor performs a cameo, it is proper to say these 2 sentences interchangeably "Michael Fassbender (MF) sale en esta película" or "MF aparece en esta película" or even "MF hace un cameo en esta película", but if the actor has an important role in the movie and is credited, it's proper to say "MF actúa en esa película". HOWEVER, in some cultures people nowadays tend to say "MF sale en esta película" in a popular way to say it, but now you know when to use each expression properly.

Comment: What do you mean by "featured" in the movie? No so usual in English. Is English your mother tongue?

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways we use to say this, the one you mention being one of the most common ones.

For example, in my Spanish from Spain I would use:

> M. F. aparece [en esta película]
>
> M. F. actúa [en esta película]
>
> M.F. sale [en esta película]

Note all of the expressions mean the same, all of them not making it clear if the actor is one of the main characters or if it is just a *cameo*. I don't think there is a way to state that, unless being specific (*M. F. es el protagonista / uno de los protagonistas*).

To give some references, [WordReference says](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=feature) that the translation to "feature [sb]", as per include as actor, is either of:

- tener la actuación de
- aparecer

I cannot think on a most preferred one.

Comment: In my country we simply say: ... *sale en esta película*. I think the use is regional, though.

Comment: Nótese que todas las traducciones que nos parecen más naturales corresponden a otros verbos ingleses, como _plays, acts, appears_ o _features_. La traducción directa de "**is** in it" debería ser _está en ella_ o _se encuentra en ella_ aunque, claro, no es lo más habitual.

Comment: my first thought was "estrenar" —but that is to debut, like to act for the first time, or to premiere the movie itself (show it for the first time) .. in each case "first" is part of the word. to appear in sounds like the best to me at this point: aparece

Answer (score 0):

This may be cheating the system a bit, so if anyone wants to shoot this down and direct me to add it as just a comment I will, but, in the meantime, the OP, may find some usefulness in this discussion thread here

> [**Besides "Who works?" what meanings can "¿Quién trabaja?" have?**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/37127/besides-who-works-what-meanings-can-qui%C3%A9n-trabaja-have)

and posting it in an answer means it is less likely to be overlooked.