# Besides "Who works?" what meanings can "¿Quién trabaja?" have?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones

I was doing an [**Instituto Cervantes**](https://cvc.cervantes.es/ensenanza/actividades_ave/nivelI/actividad_15.htm) activity when I came across the following dialog:

[image]

Via context, it is pretty clear that

> **¿Quién trabaja?**

doesn't mean "Who works?"  I am guessing it means something like "Who is in the movie?"  Is this a common way to express this in Spanish?  Can a native speaker confirm/deny this?  (Please specify your country of origin or the country where such usage occurs.)

Also, is there a comprehensive compilation of Spanish usage  containing various expressions (such as this)?

---

Estaba haciendo una actividad del [**Instituto Cervantes**](https://cvc.cervantes.es/ensenanza/actividades_ave/nivelI/actividad_15.htm) cuando me encontré con el siguiente diálogo:

[Véanse arriba en la sección inglesa.]

A través del contexto, es bastante claro que

> **¿Quién trabaja?**

no significa "¿Who works?" en este ejemplo.  Supongo que significa algo así como "¿Quién está en la película?"  ¿Es una forma común de expresar esto en español?  ¿Puede un hablante nativo confirmar/rechazar esto?  (Por favor, especifiquen su país de origen o el país en el que se usa.)

Además, ¿hay una compilación completa del uso del español que contenga varias expresiones (como esta)?

*Traducción realizada (en parte) con la versión gratuita del traductor [www.DeepL.com/Translator.](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator.)*

Comment: I guess this is regional, as I have never heard that in Spain...

Comment: @wimi Quite possible.  After all, with the exception of Eusebio Poncela, all of the actors mentioned are Argentinian (not to mention the film itself).  Another thing to consider is that sometimes language in source material may be borderline obsolete, even if copyrights are current.  This is a topic of conversation all by itself.  Be that as it may, thank you for your comment.  You hinted at something that added something additionally valuable to this discussion.

Answer (score 5):

El verbo que primero se me viene a la mente para hablar de algún actor que aparece en una película, es "salir", que según el diccionario tiene esta acepción:

> 24. intr. En una función de teatro o en una película, representar, figurar o hacer un papel. Ella salió de doña Inés.

Así, diría frases como:

- ¿Quién es la actriz que sale con Tom Cruise en Top Gun?
- ¿Adónde más sale esta fulana?
- Nick, el que salía en CSI, ahora sale en MacGyver.

La verdad es que yo nunca he oído decir que alguien "trabaja" o que alguien "está" en tal película. Pero otras formas como yo lo diría son las siguientes:

- ¿Quiénes son los actores principales de La casa de papel?
- ¿Quienes salen en La niña?
- ¿Con quién es la nueva versión de Batman?
- ¿Quién interpreta a Jean Valjean en Les misérables?
- ¿Cuál es el elenco del Fantasma de la ópera?
- ¿Quiénes son los protagonistas de El silencio de los inocentes?
- ¿En qué películas aparece Marion Cotillard?
- ¿Cuáles películas ha hecho Johnny Depp?

Comment: I like your answer, chapelo.  Do you happen to have any examples from literature or news broadcasts?

Comment: If you can, I will award you the green check mark, although I will need to reword the initial question slightly.  Initially, I was thinking there might be more idiomatic expressions with "trabajar" and perhaps there are, but based on what little this question yielded, I think a better question might be something like _What's another way to ask "Who is in the movie?" besides "¿Quién está en la película?"_

Comment: @LisaBeck I just edited the answer to answer your previous comment.

Comment: Thank you for the additional examples.  They are excellent.  However, what I was attempting to ask is, besides your own personal conversational experiences, where have you heard or seen such phrases?  Do you have any examples from books, newspaper articles, movies, news broadcasts, et cetera?  I'm not doubting that what you say isn't true.  I'd just love to be able to refer to a real life (or fictional) example of such usage.

Comment: For example, if I wanted to do the same for the phrase "the show must go on," I might add an example like [**this**](https://getyarn.io/yarn-story/e4601cdd-6fc4-4deb-8ead-985459c82f81).  Here's another for [**"Who's in it?"**](https://getyarn.io/yarn-story/c0d39d4a-c326-4542-9ba7-0c572e25bca8). Do you see what I'm requesting now? 
 Your examples don't need to be actual video clips, but quotes from the sources I mentioned previously would be interesting and helpful.  Thanks if you can!

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: yes, "¿quién trabaja?" when speaking about a movie is a usual question to mean "who acts/performs in the movie?".

Other possible questions, similarly idiomatic, are:

- ¿Quién actúa?
- ¿Quién está (en la película)?

Comment: In that same context, "¿De quién es?" would mean "¿Quién es el director?".

Comment: @Gaviota Exactly.